# Is there a way to make TextSpan.text selectable in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I've a webpage made with flutter. I'm using `RichText` to make paragraphs and each of those have `TextSpan` children widgets. I want to make them selectable, searchable(when ctrl+f is used within the webpage) and on-page seo friendly.

Is there a way to achieve it without using `SelectableText` as it doesn't suits my usecase?

Answer (score 2):

try [extended_text](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text)

or

have you tried SelectableText.rich?

```
SelectableText.rich(
  TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'Hello '),
      TextSpan(
        text: 'bold',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Yup it works but there is still a small problem, I can't select text written in multiple SelectableText.rich widgets all at once.

Comment: Also for some reason ctrl+f behaviour is a bit stange, it only searches for text within the TextSpan which was selected lately. And if none was selected then it doesn't successfully searches for text.

Comment: you right bro... what about try this package, extended_text